# MS SQL complex update query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I've multiple tables and try to update some tables based on matching translation in master tables. I could update the table based on the first available translation, but I would like to do it based on the most frequent one. I found quite a lot of samples on how to achieve that in simple queries, but can't have it work in this complex query below.

In brief I just need to take the most frequent translation [target] from [EC3_800_FR_M] and copy it to [EC3_800_FR], instead of taking the first occurence in the table.

```
UPDATE [ec3_800_fr] 
SET    [ec3_800_fr].[target] = (SELECT TOP 1 
       [ec3_800_fr_m].[target] 
FROM   [ec3_800_fr_m] 
WHERE  ( 
       [ec3_800_fr].[enus] = [ec3_800_fr_m].[enus]           AND 
       [ec3_800_fr].[length] = [ec3_800_fr_m].[length]            AND 
       [ec3_800_fr].[key6_domainname] = [ec3_800_fr_m].[key6_domainname] AND  
       [ec3_800_fr_m].[status] > 1 
       )
       );
```

who can help me???
merci - thank you - Dank u - Danke
BR
lolo

Comment: How do you define the most frequent? the count? It looks like you are updating every record in `EC3_800_FR` with the same value - is that what you want?

Comment: I'm not updating every record with the same value. I'm updating the matching translations only. It seems to work at least :-)
basically target of table EC3_800_FR is fed by target of table EC3_800_FR_M in the case enUS is the same and under some other conditions. I ran it over 290.000 entries in EC3_800_FR and there were 50.000 entries in EC3_800_FR_M. About 8000 entries have been updated in EC3_800_FR. the only issue is that within the same domain, and for the same source text, there might be multiple available translations, and I'd like to use the most frequent one instead of the first one.

Comment: You still haven't defined 'most 'frequent' is it the record count? Also please specify the type of database in the tags, i.e. SQL Server 2008?

Comment: If you remove your database and schema qualifications as they do not seem to have any impact it will make your query a bit easier to view. And when you define frequent, people will be able to help you more. Generally what you're looking for is simply a subquery of the most "frequent", which you then can join into your base table and use update on that join condition. It's relative easy but requires us to know the table layout and the logic for "frequent". Also which database engine you're working on will also be nice, as syntax has different flavors depending on which database you're using.

Comment: sorry - frequent signification:

Comment: sorry - frequent signification: within the ec3_800_fr_m table, there might be several occurences of the same enUS with different targets (=translations). e.g. for ABC, we might have DEF or DEV as targets. We might have 2x DEF and 3 times DEVs. with the current query, it will take the first, whereas I'd like the most frequent...
The table layout is pretty simple. The relevant fields are [enUS] & [target] in both tables. the 3 other fields I'm using are length (in both tables), which is the max length (=external constraint, not the field max len), and the domain name.

Comment: You basically need to use COUNT(*) and GROUP BY to find the frequency. Is this on `SQL 2008 R2`? If so please add that tag. If not add an appropriate database tag.

Comment: It is on SQL server 2008 R2. I have added the tag now.